# Bash | pipe to bash function

Tags: linux, bash, function, pipe, stdin

In the attempt to pipe to a Bash function, I wrote this:

```
example () {
    if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then local S=${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}; else local S="$1"; fi
    #echo "$S"
    echo "$S" | tr ' ' '_'
}
echo 'Moizès Júnior' | example
example 'Moizès Júnior'

Moizès_Júnior
Moizès_Júnior
```

However, in another context I am receiving the correct output plus this error message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Trying to debug it I ask if there is something wrong the way I am writing the code inside the function in order to get STDIN.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Who cores? Bash? Try `type <core-dump-file>`

Comment: file <core-dump-file> should also give you the name of the file.

Comment: Please, where do I use `file <core-dump-file>`?

Comment: You type it into your shell, replacing `<core-dump-file>` with the name of the core file that the error message you posted indicates should have been created. :-)  It might be `bash.core` or just `core` or something else. Try running `ls -lt | head` to see what files were created recently in your current directory.

Comment: The only message I received (besides the script output) is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". And I can notice anything abnormal after `ls -lt | head`.

Comment: FYI -- `local var=$(something)` is actually an antipattern, because it has the exit status of `local` (always success) instead of the exit status of `something`. Better to `local var; var=$(something)`.

Comment: Also, it's a little odd to be looking only at whether `$1` is empty but then concatenating all of `$@` (which it isn't defined behavior to assign to a string anyhow, by the way -- use `$*` instead in that case). If you want to look at whether there are any arguments, look at `$#` -- otherwise, `example '' "hello"` will try to read from stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bash` is responsible for the core dump, that certainly indicates a bug in `bash` that should be reported. However, your function can be written more simply as

```
example () {
    local S
    if (( "$#" == 0 )); then
        IFS= read -r S
        set -- "$S"
    fi
    echo "${1// /_}"
}
```

which may, at least, avoid the bug.

Comment: Why you say this is more simple (taking out the `tr ' ' '_'` part, which was given only as an example, it could be anything else)? Is your code more efficient? I find it harder to understand. Specially the `set -- "$S"` part.

Comment: How does it not work, or are you trying `example Moizès Júnior` instead of `example "Moizès Júnior"`?

Comment: I mean `emample 'Moizès Júnior'`.

Comment: @Roger, `set -- "$S"` sets `$1` to be equal to `"$S"`. Just because something is *unfamiliar* doesn't make it *complex*. (Aside: the talk by Rich Hickey, "Simple Made Easy", does a very good job of teasing apart all these concepts to help one think about them separately... a process for which he would suggest the word "decomplecting").

Comment: @chepner, ...the only change I might make here is `IFS= read -r -d '' S || [[ $S ]]` or such, to be able to read multi-line strings.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommending reading the whole stdin into a variable. Instead of:

```
#the main "worker" function always uses stdin/out
example_worker() { tr ' ' '_'; }

#the switcher
example() { if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then example_worker; else example_worker <<< "$1"; fi ; }

echo 'a b c' | example
example 'a b c'
#but also
example < multi_giga_file.txt
```

Comment: Imagine I have many functions like "example_worker1", "example_worker2", "example_worker3", "example_worker4"... all with similar behavior the "example_worker" of yours. How would you deal with that @jm666 ?

Comment: @Roger it is not clear what you want achieve. Want call multiple workers in a row (sequentially - aka like a pipe?) or only one at time, but based on some conditions? You need be clear when asking for help. This question already got answers, so probably would be the best ask a new question with new (more precisely defined) case, moreover you example code isn't trying to call "mutiple" workers...